# Rust lifetime in struct with thread_local

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to use the Windows API to write a Windows GUI program, using `thread_local` to save all the created windows or buttons.

```
use std::thread::Thread;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

// button window checkbox need impl this trait.
trait Wnd{
    fn CreateWindow(&self)->int
    {
        // do some thing
        0
    }
}

pub struct Dust{
  window_counter:int,
  hInstance:int,
  hookId: int,
  widgets:HashMap<int, Rc<RefCell<Wnd>>>,
}

fn dust()->RefCell<Dust>{
  unsafe{
    let mut d = Dust{
      window_counter:0,
      hInstance:0,
      hookId:0,
      widgets: HashMap::new(),
    };

    return RefCell::new(d)
  }
}

pub thread_local!(static TLS_DUST: RefCell<Dust> = dust());


fn main()
{

    TLS_DUST.with( | d | {
        let mut dust = d.borrow_mut();
        dust.window_counter-=1;
    });

}
```

when I build I got the error:

```
$ cargo build --verbose
   Compiling dust v0.0.1 (file:///D:/msys64/home/BYWAYBOY/dust/examples)
     Running `rustc D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\src\lib.rs --crate-name dust --crate-type lib -g -C metadata=3fbf7f518595f4d2 -C extra-filename=-3fbf7f518595f4d2 --out-dir D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\examples\target\deps --emit=dep-info,link -L D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\examples\target\deps -L D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\examples\target\deps`
D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\src\lib.rs:52:36: 52:39 error: explicit lifetime bound required
D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\src\lib.rs:52   widgets:HashMap<HWND, Rc<RefCell<Wnd>>>,
                                                                              ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `dust`.

Caused by:
  Process didn't exit successfully: `rustc D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\src\lib.rs --crate-name dust --crate-type lib -g -C metadata=3fbf7f518595f4d2 -C extra-filename=-3fbf7f518595f4d2 --out-dir D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\examples\target\deps --emit=dep-info,link -L D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\examples\target\deps -L D:\msys64\home\BYWAYBOY\dust\examples\target\deps` (status=101)
```

I just want use the HashMap to store all windows and widgets in a `thread_local`.

Comment: You didn't paste enough of your error, it doesn't include the line of code that it's complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rust playpen with a version of your code that compiles: http://is.gd/1vAihA

Below is the code copied from the playpen, let me explain what I changed.

The error that you mention above was coming from your Dust struct declaration, specifically the `widgets` field. `Wnd` is a trait, and the type of the `widget` field is using the trait object type. The trait object type allows for dynamic dispatch during runtime, however, as the compiler says, you need to specify a lifetime bound on the trait object.

I specified the special lifetime bound, `static`, because you are using this with the `thread_local!` macro and declaring `TLS_DUST` as static. `'static` essentially says that this variable will live for the entire lifetime of the program.

After that error was fixed, `rustc` hit another error related to `Wnd` not being of kind `Sized`. `Sized` is a kind that specifies that a type has a known size at compile-time. Since `Wnd` is a trait object and thus could potentially be any number of different sizes, we have to wrap it in a `Box<T>` (think of `Box<T>` as a unique pointer type).

I also took the opportunity to write an `impl` for `Dust`. This is a more idiomatic way of creating a new variable of some type, `Dust::new()`. I kept your `dust()` function to wrap the new `Dust` struct in a `RefCell`.

Finally, I fixed some `rustc` warnings related to camel case code, rust usually uses underscores to separate words.

Code:

```
use std::thread::Thread;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashMap;

// button window checkbox need impl this trait.
trait Wnd {
    fn create_window(&self) -> int
    {
        // do some thing
        0
    }
}

struct Dust {
  window_counter: int,
  h_instance: int,
  hook_id: int,
  widgets: HashMap<int, Rc<RefCell<Box<Wnd + 'static>>>>, //'
}

impl Dust {
    fn new() -> Dust {
        Dust {
            window_counter:0,
            h_instance:0,
            hook_id:0,
            widgets: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn dust() -> RefCell<Dust> {
        RefCell::new(Dust::new())
    }
}

pub thread_local!(static TLS_DUST: RefCell<Dust> = Dust::dust());

fn main()
{
    TLS_DUST.with( | d | {
        let mut dust = d.borrow_mut();
        dust.window_counter-=1;
    });
}
```